# No UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3, swift2

Sometimes when I call this code when the UICollectionView is not ready (Instantly after calling `collectionView.reloadData()`), it crashes the app

```
        let sectionHeaderAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = self.collectionView.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath)!;
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no
>   UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for
>   -layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader at path  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'

How do I check if the UICollectionView is "ready" before I call the code? How do we guard to prevent the crash from happening?

Comment: Are you sure your collection view has a header after you call reload? Can you add more code to your question as well? Not sure why you're trying to get the layout attributes of the header.